# How do I specify MongoDB key/value parameters in an $http.get with an AngularJS controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

I'm using the MEAN stack for a web app. In my controller.js, I have the following:

```js
var refresh3 = function() {
    $http.get('/users').success(function(response) {
        console.log("I got the data I requested");
        $scope.users = response;
        $scope.contact3 = "";
    });
};

refresh3();
```

This pulls back every object in the "users" collection from my MongoDB. How could I add parameters to this to bring back, for example, only objects where "name" : "Bob" ? I have tried adding parameters in the '/users' parentheses using:

```js
$http.get('/users', {params:{"name":"Bob"}})
```

I've also tried variants of that, but no luck. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $http.get('/users', {params:{"name":"Bob"}}) seems correct; please define "no luck"

Comment: by default its goes to server as query string unless you specify in $resource, to make actual like /users/bob. in both cases, you still have req.query or req.params accessible in server side code.

Comment: "no luck" meaning either the controller breaks and I don't get any data back, or I get the same data I would have expected without any parameters.

Comment: please check whether the data is passed alongside your query (as a query string: you can use developer tools in your browser) and whether it is received by your server; does your mean stack use Mongoose?

Comment: Other parts of the site use mongoose, but this part specifically is using MongoJS.

Comment: ok, fine, just let us know whether the data is properly sent, and what the server receives

Comment: just a thought: does your server use restify along with MongoJS? Is it properly set to respond to get with query string?

Comment: here's the corresponding request from my server file: `app.get('/users', function (req, res) {
 console.log("I received a GET request")

 db.users.find(function (err, docs) {
  console.log(docs);
  res.json(docs);
 });
});`

Comment: well I feel it is a server conf issue, rather than an angularjs issue. What does console.log(req.body) give in your server? If your server does receive your params, then it's just a matter of setting MongoJS to react appropriately, and do sth like: db.users.find({"name":"Bob"},function(err,docs){...});

Comment: @MikeJoyce I posted an answer, corresponding to the case where your server is properly receiving the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### If your server is receiving the data

(and it should, as `$http.get('/users', {params:{"name":"Bob"}})` is correct)

On server side, make use of the query string:

```
req.query
```

like so:

```
app.get('/users', function(req,res){
  if(req.query.name){
    db.users.find({"name":req.query.name},function (err, docs) { console.log(docs); res.json(docs); }); 
  }
  else{
    db.users.find(function (err, docs) { console.log(docs); res.json(docs); });
  }
});
```

---

WHAT WAS THE ISSUE?

You hinted in your comments that your server was set to respond to the `app.get('/users')` GET request like so:

```
db.users.find(function (err, docs) {
 // docs is an array of all the documents in users collection
 console.log(docs); res.json(docs); }); });
```

So I believe that your angularjs $http get is correct, and your server is receiving the parameters `{"name":"Bob"}` as it should;
it just doesn't know what to do with them:
all it is set to do is to return the whole collection in the particular case of a `app.get('/users')` GET request.

---

HOW TO CONFIGURE YOUR SERVER FOR REST

You do not have to re-invent the wheel on the server.

Rather, you could consider using a middleware to automate the task (in the present case, the task is to issue a proper MongoDb request when you receive a get query with parameters from the client)

e.g. [express-restify-mongoose middleware](https://github.com/florianholzapfel/express-restify-mongoose)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Would you be able to clarify where the "if" statement goes in relation to the original app.get?

Comment: Excellent remark: got the statement mangled; will rewrite when access to proper computer in 5 min

Comment: ok, I rewrote the "if" statement the way I had originally planned to; but the point is that manually taking care of all possible queries is painful and error prone; it is way easier to rely on a tool especially designed for rest queries, like the one I provided a link to

Comment: by the way, I assumed your server was getting the data (ie the request with the {"name":"Bob"} in the query string). Is it the case?

Comment: Hey the new code worked man, I really appreciate it. I will definitely look into the tool you linked to. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: To your second comment, I actually hadn't checked. Every one said the params syntax looked right, so I kinda took that for granted (bad practice, i know!)